# Export Excel Spread Sheet to Access Table with A Timestamp?

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, insert-into, vba

I currently use a set up like the one below.

```
Set AccessConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

sExcel = "[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[Sheet1$]"

AccessConn.Open "DSN=Foo", "", ""


sSQL = "Insert Into BarTable Select * FROM " + sExcel


AccessConn.Execute sSQL
```

Now if I wanted to add a now() column in the export is this possible? something like

```
Set AccessConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

sExcel = "[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[Sheet1$]"

AccessConn.Open "DSN=Foo", "", ""


sSQL = "Insert Into BarTable Select *,NOW() FROM " + sExcel


AccessConn.Execute sSQL
```

Where the last column in BarTable is a Date/Time column and I want to insert the current time into it?

Answer (score 0):

to enter the date in SQL you may need to convert it into text - Access itself can handle 'Now()' but not sure if it can when being passed a SQL string. Something like the below should do it.

```
sSQL = "Insert Into BarTable Select *,#" & format(NOW(),"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss") & "# As DateTimeStamp FROM " + sExcel
```

In Access I have two functions that I use for getting the date or date and time stamp when building SQL strings, I haven't tested but they should translate into Excel VBA okay:

```
Function MakeSQLDateTime(pSourceDate As Variant) As String
    Dim SQLDay As String, SQLMonth As String, SQLYear As String, SQLTime As String


    SQLDay = Day(pSourceDate)
    SQLMonth = Month(pSourceDate)
    SQLYear = Right(Year(pSourceDate), 4)
    SQLTime = Hour(pSourceDate) & ":" & Minute(pSourceDate) & ":" & Second(pSourceDate)
    MakeSQLDateTime = "#" & SQLMonth & "/" & SQLDay & "/" & SQLYear & " " & SQLTime & "#"
End Function

Function MakeSQLDate(pSourceDate As Variant) As String
    Dim SQLDay As String
    Dim SQLMonth As String
    Dim SQLYear As String

    SQLDay = Day(pSourceDate)
    SQLMonth = Month(pSourceDate)
    SQLYear = Right(Year(pSourceDate), 4)
    MakeSQLDate = "#" & SQLMonth & "/" & SQLDay & "/" & SQLYear & "#"
End Function
```

To use these to complete what you are trying:

```
sSQL = "Insert Into BarTable Select *," & makeSQLDateTime(Now()) & " As DateTimeStamp FROM " + sExcel
```